# VBA integer division using Decimal datatype

Tags: vba

I'm trying to divide a variable `x` of type `Decimal` by another `Decimal` `y` and get only the integer result, but I'm getting an overflow error.

```
Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Variant

a = CDec(129801938493)
b = CDec(9385029380)

a = a \ b
```

Apparently the `\` operator coerces its arguments to the `Long` datatype.  Is there a way to do integer division (or modulo division) using `Decimal`?

Comment: Note that your example demonstrates [integer division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_division#Division_of_integers), not [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). I fixed your title accordingly.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, thanks.  For the algorithm I'm working with, either integer division or modulo division is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = Int(a / b)
```

The Int function truncates, so that should work the same as "\".